# Logic of the install in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I code in Dreamweaver as a student, and I have been looking into Wordpress for later coding ventures.

I was looking around and read that you can install Wordpress using a .php file or something along those lines.

What is the point of that? I thought that Wordpress sites were coded through a web interface.

Comment: The wordpress installer collects user preferences/settings and then does a whole bunch of environment setup. It will (attempt to) set file permissions as they should be, create necessary directories and config files, instantiate databases, etc. Saves a lot of work on the end-user deploying it to their site.

Comment: Bit confusing to me. From what Ive seen, it allows you to set up hosting of the site, instead of going directly through wordpress (but allows you to use that as your way of building the site). Thats what ive gathered so far, dont know if thats on the rght track

Comment: Sorry do you have a specific question? I'm not certain what you're asking.

Comment: *Not too much code related.* -- off topic, then. Not too much Stack Overflow related.

Comment: @CollinD So theoretically, if I wanted to host a website, why would I do a wordpress install when I could code directly through wordpress site?

Comment: Installing a framework is the same thing as installing **anything**: set up variables, allocate files where they should be, draw application primary custom flow. Your questions suggests you don't understand what is a framework. But your question remains off topic anyway.

Comment: Maybe you want more direct control of your site, maybe you already have hosting and you'd like it to be hosted on your existing stack. Any number of reasons.

Comment: Cool thanks. Got what I was looking for @CollinD